# RabbitMQ - strange disk_free

Tags: rabbitmq

I've just installed Erlang and RabbitMQ.

> .\rabbitmqctl.bat status
>
> [...] {disk_free_limit,1000000000}, {disk_free,2010} [...]

Why there's 2010? I have 143GB free on this drive. Because of this i've got the following errors in RabbitMQ logs:

> =INFO REPORT==== 17-Jun-2013::17:11:09 === Disk free limit set to 1000MB
>
> =INFO REPORT==== 17-Jun-2013::17:11:09 === Disk free space insufficient. Free bytes:2010 Limit:1000000000
>
> =WARNING REPORT==== 17-Jun-2013::17:11:09 === disk resource limit alarm set on node 'rabbit@USER-PC'.
>
> ---
>
> *** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
>
> ---

How can i change it manually? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: why is the diskfree limit set to only 1GB?

Comment: @robthewolf idk. How can i change this manually?

Comment: I,m having the same problem. Free disk space is reported as 2010 bytes. I disabled "disk free limit" by setting the config file to: 
[
    {rabbit, [{disk_free_limit, 0}]}
].
to try rabbitmq.

Comment: @hamdiakoguz Where did you found config file for RabbitMQ on Windows?

Comment: @nikita-trophimov Initially it does not exist. I created the rabbitmq.config file under %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\

Comment: @hamdiakoguz Do i need to enter the full path to this config file anywhere?

Comment: @nikita-trophimov No, that is the default place. You can change it if you like by setting RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE environment variable.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? We're having the same problem, there is loads of space on the disk but we're seeing 2.0kB free space reported in Rabbit.

Comment: @Joe Taylor Unfortunately, no. Can you say me your RabbitMQ version, etc?

Comment: I'm having this issue as well: Windows 8, Rabbit 3.1.3, erl R16. Is this a 3.1.3 regression on some systems, or are you all running different versions?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, and I seem to have got to the root cause.

Rabbit uses `os:cmd("dir /-C /W \"" ++ Dir ++ [$]")` [here](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-server/file/23a25fcfd007/src/rabbit_disk_monitor.erl#l171) to run dir and get the free space on the disk drive.

But... I have Clink (http://code.google.com/p/clink) installed, which wraps cmd.exe.

Rabbit's parsing of the cmd output is fairly naive, and relies on the disk space free being on the last line:

```
parse_free_win32(CommandResult) ->
   LastLine = lists:last(string:tokens(CommandResult, "\r\n")),
   {match, [Free]} = re:run(lists:reverse(LastLine), "(\\d+)",
                            [{capture, all_but_first, list}]),
   list_to_integer(lists:reverse(Free)).
```

Running the `os:cmd("dir /-C /W \"" ++ Dir ++ [$"])` command in erl on my machine appends licence text to the end of the command output (due to Clink), and the parsing code takes the last year in the Copyright notice rather than the actual diskspace available.

I'm guessing you have something similar installed which is also affecting the result of the command being called. Running `Result = os:cmd("dir /-C /W <your dir>").` in an erlang prompt should give you a good idea.

Comment: If it is clink specifically causing your issue, you can disable the banner. Check this issue for details: https://code.google.com/p/clink/issues/detail?id=124&q=copyright

Comment: The problem is that the output is locale-specific. Rabbit command parsing is not any more naive than 99% of command line tools.

Comment: I'm not saying that being naive is a bad thing :). clink does attempt to determine if a cmd session is being run interactively or not to avoid exactly these types of issues, but it seems to guess wrong with os:cmd calls (someone else had issues with rebar). Fortunately, it also has a --quiet option to make the issue go away.

Comment: Thanks, registering clink with --quiet fixed the issue for me as well.